# Prolog List Operations

Tags: prolog

My problem is:

> Write a PROLOG program that, given two lists of integers INDEXS and VALUES, returns a list whose first element is the value stored in the position corresponding to the first element of INDEXS of the list VALUES.
>   For example, given INDXS=[2,1,4,3] and VALUES=[2,4,6,8], the output is [4,2,8,6].

So far I have done the following:

```
newlist([], [], void).
newlist([void|Tail], Values, X) :- newlist(Tail, Values, X).

newlist([H|T], Values, X) :- 
   nth1(H, Values, Curr), %%Get element nr H in Values and bind it to Curr
   add(Curr, X, [Curr|X]), %%Add Current to array X
   newlist(T, Values, X). %%Recursive send back Tail, the values and new array X
```

And query the following:

```
newlist([2,1], [2,3], X).
```

If my prolog code is ok, I want to show my new list in the variable X. How can I do this? (I have already tried to print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close to a solution. The simplest case is when the list of indexes is empty. In this case, the list of values is of no consequence and the result is an empty list:

```
values([], _, []).
```

The `_` is an *anonymous variable*. It can be regarded as a "don't care variable". If the list of indexes is not empty, we need to walk down the list and, for each index, retrieve the corresponding value at that position:

```
values([Index| Indexes], Values, [SelectedValue| SelectedValues]) :-
    nth1(Index, Values, SelectedValue),
    values(Indexes, Values, SelectedValues).
```

The `nth1/3` predicate is a common library predicate that you can find implemented in several Prolog systems. If it is not available in the Prolog system you are using, defining it is a good exercise to learn Prolog.

Using your example as a sample query:

```
?- values([2,1,4,3], [2,4,6,8], SelectedValues).
SelectedValues = [4, 2, 8, 6].
```

Comment: Thank you for a precise and short answer!

Answer (score 2):

For fun, you can also use `maplist`.

Define `nth_value` to move the `nth1` arguments to a convenient order:

```
nth_value(Values, Index, Item) :- nth1(Index, Values, Item).
```

Then:

```
newlist(INDXS, VALUES, R) :- maplist(nth_value(VALUES), INDXS, R).
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a standard trick   achieving this  by pairing up the indices and the values and just *sorting* the resulting list, since pairs are sorted in *lexicographical* order. The indices will get sorted, and the values will get dragged along with them and find themselves in the correct places:

```
pair_up( X, Y, X-Y).
second( _-Y, Y).

newlist( Idxs, Vals, R) :- 
     maplist( pair_up, Idxs, Vals, L), 
     sort( L, S), 
     maplist( second, S, R).
```

It is independent of the indexing scheme: both 0- and 1-based indexing will work.

Another advantage is that it is linearithmic (due to the sorting), unlike the *repeated `nth`* solutions which are quadratic.

This assumes though that you are only *rearranging* the sequence, i.e. that both argument lists `Idxs` and `Vals` are of the same length.